# Strange double border in mPDF

Tags: css, mpdf

*Edit: Completely changed this to give a minimal example.*

I'm using mPDF to turn HTML containing a table into a PDF.

To double-underline the end sum, I'm applying the CSS style `border-bottom: 3pt double black;`

This is a minimal example for reproducing the problem:

```
<?php
require_once "../../autoload.php";
$html = '<html><table><tr>
<td style="border-bottom: 5pt double black;">  style="border-bottom: 5pt double black;"  </td></tr></table>
</body></html>';
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', 20);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('test.pdf', 'F');
```

The result can be seen below, for some strange reason the two lines are connected at the ends. Is this a bug or am I doing anything wrong?

[image: Double underline (the wrong way)]

Comment: please post the code that generates this result